# Is it possible to safely monitor the Python stack on a production Linux system?

Tags: python, linux, performance, signals

A common debugging technique for performance problems during development (i.e. not in a production system) is to randomly halt the program and inspect the stack.  If you see the same or similar stacks often, that is a clue that performance problems are caused by whatever is going on when the program is doing that.

I would like to do something similar in a production system, since there is information there that could be useful in fixing performance problems, if it could be non-destructively measured.

My first thought was to send a UNIX signal to the processes in question.  A signal handler for that signal would then log the stack (logging from a signal handler presents its own complications, but they could be worked around and are not really relevant to this question).

However, that is problematic because signals may cause system calls to be interrupted, which might break otherwise working production code, either by changing its behaviour or by degrading performance through retries.  I believe the Python standard library still does not handle EINTR correctly in many places, which aggravates this problem.

Is there a way to avoid these problems, partially or fully?  The answer need not involve signals (but I'm not sure there is another way).  Note that part of the appeal of triggering the stack logging with a signal is that that should help reveal problems that occur as a result of I/O, rather than only problems that result from excessive use of CPU time.

Answer (score -1):

This seems to work:

```
import signal
import traceback

def handler(*_):
  traceback.print_stack()

signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR1, handler)
```

Python has quite some expertise baked in on how to safely handle signals, so I think this should be OK.  And it worked in my brief testing on Python 2.7.6.

Comment: Python 2 (and 3, still?) does not handle EINTR well compared to many other languages / standard libraries https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0475/

Comment: The code you write is indeed the sort of code that is problematic for production use, for the reasons I listed in the question: it may change program behaviour and performance.  A couple of sent signals is one thing but a lot of them is a potential problem. Also, in my experiment, a postgres query blocked on a db lock in select never called my SIGUSR2 signal handler - even after I subsequently sent it a SIGINT, which is when I hoped it would get around to running the python signal handler for SIGUSR2).

Comment: @CroadLangshan: Of course any signal handling scheme can impact program performance.  I think that's inevitable.  But let's talk about behavior.  Python signal handlers may be "delayed" when Python is executing C code, because of the async-signal-safe requirement.  A long-running C extension may not yield control to the Python interpreter for a while, and only after it does can signal handlers be invoked.  That's why you experience the SIGUSR2 delay.  I don't think there is any way around this, but I also think it shouldn't matter too much for the use case you have outlined.

Comment: A delay was what I was expecting.  What I saw was instead the handler not being called even after the second signal arrived and control returned to Python code.  Re performance: agreed, but the question is how significant the impact is, and in my case that appeared to be a problem.